# I'm having a syntax error writing a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Writing a simple shell script to look at a specific file that will be added to in the future, and extract information from a name, formatted like {name};{info};{more info}, is pretty straightforward, but it gives me this error and I can't figure out why the hell there's an issue, I've tried adjusting it a million ways and can't figure it out.

Error:

```
./BBoiler.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./BBoiler.sh: line 6: `     for part in $parts; do'
```

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash 
name="Chloe"
echo clients.txt | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
    parts=$(echo $line | tr ";" "\n")
    for part in $parts; do
        if[ $part == $name ]; then
            echo "$name"
        fi
    done
done

printf "$name test"
```

Comment: Silly of me to ask, but does your script have a space after if?

Comment: @MGM_Squared I'm confident it doesn't! I've used a function of my text editor to remove trailing whitespace, and moved lines around repeatedly, that's also the first thing I thought of though! should've mentioned that I tested that in the question!

Comment: I don't see anything that'd cause that problem (although the lack of a space between `if` and `[` will cause a similar error about `then`). There may be an invisible character in there somewhere (or maybe something like a non-breaking space) causing trouble; try printing the script with `cat -vt BBoiler.sh` and see if it shows anything weird. Also, `echo clients.txt` will not read that file, it'll just print the text "clients.txt" -- instead, put `< clients.txt` after the `done` for the outer loop. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out some other problems.

Comment: Which text editor are you using bash does expect a space to follow the if keyword.  I only ask about the if keyword because I got your script to work verbatim.  My text editor (vim) complained about the lack of space around the if as Gordon was saying.  However...other than that it worked for me.

Comment: *Addendum*  The script ran.  The actual expected output did not work as per the reason mentioned by Gordon.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you! I used shellcheck and made the change you suggested, and now the script runs, is there a way to give you credit for the correct answer and mark this as done?

Comment: You can always submit your corrected code as an answer and then accept your own answer after 48 hrs(?) to gain valuable reputation points (I don't think he will mnd). AND you can goto Gordon's user Profile and find (most likely) many good answers where he has not received any votes, and you can upvote them. Happy New Year to all! Cheers

Comment: Side note: `|| [[ -n $line ]]` makes no sense; just remove it.